# Stats with Git format

Tags: git, logging, format

I am trying to generate a custom git log in one-line, coma separated format that includes the number of modified lines. So far this was the closest I could get:

```
> git log --follow --pretty=format:"%h,%ci,%ae" --numstat my_file

36bddf9,2014-11-07 18:18:40 +0200,user@example.net
3       12       my_file
```

So far it looks like the custom format operators do not include stats, and all the stats options print to a new line.

How can I merge the stats info into my one-line?

Comment: maybe this helps: http://codeimpossible.com/2011/12/16/Stupid-Git-Trick-getting-contributor-stats/

Comment: AFAIK there is no native git solution. You will have to use a bash script solution or something similar as eckes link suggests.